# Wasn't able to add resource files to titanium android app

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I am building an android app using titanium and I need to add some of resource files(images and other types which usually added in project/res folder of android eclipse project) to the titanium app.

So I tried to copy couple of images - clip_first.png, clip_second.png to `[Titanium app folder]/Resources/android/images`. But when it's being compiled, the resource files are copied to the correct path but the names are with some suffices.

I attached a screen shot of the project

Is there any way to add them without the suffices? What is the naming changing rules since I saw `default.png` is also renamed to `background.png`?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot of project hierarchy]

Answer (score 1):

You should put your resources inside the folder `app/assets/android/images/res-{density}/`

Example :

```
app/assets/android/images/res-xhdpi/my_image.png
```

and then you can assign it as a background image to any view as such:

```
myView.backgroundImage = "/images/my_image.png";
```

don't forget the leading backslach on the path.

or using the tss :

```
"#myView" : {
    backgroundImage : "/images/my_image.png";
}
```

or use it with an imageview:

```
myImageView.image = "/images/my_image.png";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what about drawables with xml extension? and also what about values like strings.xml and raw resources?

Comment: And when I put the files into the path, I get some strange suffices, look like it's hash value of the file.

Comment: i'm not sure about using xml drawables in an imageView (like selectors), but what i can say is you use the attributes like backgroundImage, selectedBackgroundImage directly on any view.

for the Strings xml you'll have to use the i18 folder, i think you should really go through the docs : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Internationalization